# How to combine a first line with several next lines?

Tags: awk, csv

I have data that I have filtered and made a CSV file like this:

```
%%TRACERT: IPTYPE=IPv4, LOCALIP4="10.10.10.10", PEERIP4="20.20.20.20", MAXHOP=10;%%
1,3,1,1,1,10.10.10.10
2,3,1,1,1,10.37.112.5
3,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,Timeout
4,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,Timeout
5,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,Timeout
6,3,1,1,1,20.20.20.20
%%TRACERT: IPTYPE=IPv4, LOCALIP4="30.30.30.30", PEERIP4="40.40.40.40", MAXHOP=10;%%
1,3,1,1,1,30.30.30.30
2,3,1,1,1,30.30.30.30
3,3,1,1,1,30.30.30.30
4,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,Timeout
5,3,1,1,1,40.40.40.40
6,3,1,1,1,40.40.40.40
7,3,1,1,1,40.40.40.40
%%TRACERT: IPTYPE=IPv4, LOCALIP4="50.50.50.50", PEERIP4="60.60.60.60", MAXHOP=10;%%
1,3,1,10,1,50.50.50.50
2,3,1,1,1,50.50.50.50
3,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,Timeout
4,3,1,1,1,50.50.50.50
5,3,1,1,1,50.50.50.50
6,3,1,1,1,60.60.60.60
7,3,1,1,1,60.60.60.60
8,3,1,1,1,60.60.60.60
```

I want to every %%TRACERT line fill the hops like this:

```
1,3,1,1,1,10.10.10.10,%%TRACERT: IPTYPE=IPv4, LOCALIP4="10.10.10.10", PEERIP4="20.20.20.20", MAXHOP=10;%%
2,3,1,1,1,10.37.112.5,%%TRACERT: IPTYPE=IPv4, LOCALIP4="10.10.10.10", PEERIP4="20.20.20.20", MAXHOP=10;%%
3,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,Timeout,%%TRACERT: IPTYPE=IPv4, LOCALIP4="10.10.10.10", PEERIP4="20.20.20.20", MAXHOP=10;%%
4,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,Timeout,%%TRACERT: IPTYPE=IPv4, LOCALIP4="10.10.10.10", PEERIP4="20.20.20.20", MAXHOP=10;%%
5,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,Timeout,%%TRACERT: IPTYPE=IPv4, LOCALIP4="10.10.10.10", PEERIP4="20.20.20.20", MAXHOP=10;%%
6,3,1,1,1,20.20.20.20,%%TRACERT: IPTYPE=IPv4, LOCALIP4="10.10.10.10", PEERIP4="20.20.20.20", MAXHOP=10;%%
1,3,1,1,1,30.30.30.30,%%TRACERT: IPTYPE=IPv4, LOCALIP4="30.30.30.30", PEERIP4="40.40.40.40", MAXHOP=10;%%
2,3,1,1,1,30.30.30.30,%%TRACERT: IPTYPE=IPv4, LOCALIP4="30.30.30.30", PEERIP4="40.40.40.40", MAXHOP=10;%%
3,3,1,1,1,30.30.30.30,%%TRACERT: IPTYPE=IPv4, LOCALIP4="30.30.30.30", PEERIP4="40.40.40.40", MAXHOP=10;%%
4,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,Timeout,%%TRACERT: IPTYPE=IPv4, LOCALIP4="30.30.30.30", PEERIP4="40.40.40.40", MAXHOP=10;%%
5,3,1,1,1,40.40.40.40,%%TRACERT: IPTYPE=IPv4, LOCALIP4="30.30.30.30", PEERIP4="40.40.40.40", MAXHOP=10;%%
6,3,1,1,1,40.40.40.40,%%TRACERT: IPTYPE=IPv4, LOCALIP4="30.30.30.30", PEERIP4="40.40.40.40", MAXHOP=10;%%
7,3,1,1,1,40.40.40.40,%%TRACERT: IPTYPE=IPv4, LOCALIP4="30.30.30.30", PEERIP4="40.40.40.40", MAXHOP=10;%%
1,3,1,10,1,50.50.50.50,%%TRACERT: IPTYPE=IPv4, LOCALIP4="50.50.50.50", PEERIP4="60.60.60.60", MAXHOP=10;%%
2,3,1,1,1,50.50.50.50,%%TRACERT: IPTYPE=IPv4, LOCALIP4="50.50.50.50", PEERIP4="60.60.60.60", MAXHOP=10;%%
3,0,NULL,NULL,NULL,Timeout,%%TRACERT: IPTYPE=IPv4, LOCALIP4="50.50.50.50", PEERIP4="60.60.60.60", MAXHOP=10;%%
4,3,1,1,1,50.50.50.50,%%TRACERT: IPTYPE=IPv4, LOCALIP4="50.50.50.50", PEERIP4="60.60.60.60", MAXHOP=10;%%
5,3,1,1,1,50.50.50.50,%%TRACERT: IPTYPE=IPv4, LOCALIP4="50.50.50.50", PEERIP4="60.60.60.60", MAXHOP=10;%%
6,3,1,1,1,60.60.60.60,%%TRACERT: IPTYPE=IPv4, LOCALIP4="50.50.50.50", PEERIP4="60.60.60.60", MAXHOP=10;%%
7,3,1,1,1,60.60.60.60,%%TRACERT: IPTYPE=IPv4, LOCALIP4="50.50.50.50", PEERIP4="60.60.60.60", MAXHOP=10;%%
8,3,1,1,1,60.60.60.60,%%TRACERT: IPTYPE=IPv4, LOCALIP4="50.50.50.50", PEERIP4="60.60.60.60", MAXHOP=10;%%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So save lines that start with `%%TRACRT:` and then append them to the following liens:

```
awk '/^%%TRACERT:/ {sfx = $0; next} {print $0 "," sfx}' data
```

Answer (score 1):

Using any `sed`, you store the `%%TRACERT` lines in the `h`old space and `d`elete them, while other lines get the hold space appended with `G` and replaceing the newline (caused by appending) with a comma:

```
sed '/%%TRACERT/{h;d;};G;s/\n/,/' file.csv
```